# In ublock, How to block (pick) an element that keep reappearing as one scroll the page?

Tags: adblock, ublock-origin, ublock

The picker works when the page loads, but as I scroll the item reappears again and again.

How to block an item like that?

Comment: It depends what that element is. We'll need to know what it is in order to figure out how to block it.

Comment: You don’t have to use the picker. You can also use browser devtools and create the selector yourself.